# Drop a virtual file to a FileDrop receiving target

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have an sftp client, and would like to drag virtual files from my listview (actually ObjectListView) to desktop, or other target accepting drop file. I can drag files from desktop to my listview and then upload it.

The file being dropped is not present on the local filesystem, at the time of drag/drop.

I am not too familiar with drag/drop, so if anyone has any resources related to this, please post them.

Most related drag/drop questions doesn't answer my specific question as far as I looked.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Aderito No luck yet, paused on this for the time being, waiting for an answer here. Would start a bounty but I already have little rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for my answer to this question: [Drag and drop virtual files using IStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187444/drag-and-drop-virtual-files-using-istream). I must say, that task you want to implement is not easy to do, and (from what I know) there is no simple, working solution on the net for this.
But I've implemented such task by myself in .net, so it is possible of course. You can find all necessary details in the link above.